# Add a new off topic reason

Tags: feature-request

I think that we need to add something about asking for resources to the list of off topic flag reasons. It isn't uncommon to see questions asking for drumless tracks, or for a good sound editor.

Comment: Either that or merge this into the shopping recommendations reason

Comment: Why do you feel that those should be closed? Make a big list answer with community wikis and close as duplicates instead of scaring away users with *Move along, we don't deal with those..* attitude. Every network has such answers including SO. That way people are redirected not **turned down** while keeping the place neat and tidy.

Comment: @percusse Those questions have never been on-topic. They were just more widely accepted in the past

Comment: So why insist on the rules instead of the practice?

Comment: @percusse Look at it any way you want. They are off topic, and we should have a close reason that states this

Comment: Fine. But then you have a problem with *we*.